# ACF - Get lowest & highest value from field

Tags: wp-query, loop, advanced-custom-fields

I am using Advanced Custom Fields to get a list of properties as follows:-

```
        <?php
            $args = array(
                'posts_per_page'=> -1,
                'post_type'     => 'properties',
                'meta_key'      => 'development',
                'meta_value'    => $development_id
            );
            $the_query = new WP_Query( $args ); 

        ?>
        <?php if( $the_query->have_posts() ): ?>
            <?php while( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                <?php the_title(); ?>
                <?php the_field('price'); ?>
                Plot <?php the_field('plot_no'); ?>
                </div>
            <?php endwhile; ?>
        <?php endif; wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

The following; `<?php the_field('price'); ?>‘` returns:-

`325000 489950 329000 325000 294995 199950 294995 252950 325000 257950 197950 325000`

What I need is to get the lowest and highest value as a variable, any ideas how I would do this?

Comment: is each price field a single value, or multiple values separated by spaces?

Comment: multiple values separated by spaces

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got it working in the end with the below code:

```
    <?php
        $args = array(
            'posts_per_page'=> -1,
            'post_type'     => 'properties',
            'meta_key'      => 'development',
            'meta_value'    => $development_id,
        );
        $properties_query = new WP_Query( $args ); 
        $prices = array();

        if( $properties_query->have_posts() ):
            while( $properties_query->have_posts() ) : $properties_query->the_post();
                $price = get_field('price'); 
                if(isset($price) && !empty($price)){
                    $prices[] = $price; 
                }
            endwhile;
            $max_price = max($prices);
            $min_price = min($prices);

        endif; wp_reset_query(); 
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing whether  returns a single value, an array, or a string of values separated by spaces, I'd suggest something like:

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page'=> -1,
    'post_type'     => 'properties',
    'meta_key'      => 'development',
    'meta_value'    => $development_id
);
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args ); 

?>
<?php if( $the_query->have_posts() ): ?>
<?php while( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
    <?php $min_price = $max_price = ''; ?>
    <div class="col-md-4">
    <?php the_title(); ?>
    <?php 
        $price = get_the_field('price'); 
        if( $price ) {
            // if it's an array already:
            $min_price = min($price);
            $max_price = max($price);

            // if it's not an array already:
            $prices = explode(' ', $price);
            $min_price = min($prices);
            $max_price = max($prices);            
        }
        ?>
    <?php the_field('price'); ?>
    Plot <?php the_field('plot_no'); ?>
    </div>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; wp_reset_query(); ?>
```